# Установка sendmail на Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, smtp, sendmail, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Как установить sendmail на Linux (в данном случае это Raspbian на Raspberry Pi, но это не принципиально), чтобы не использовать сторонние SMTP.

Т.е. чтобы почту отправлять именно с данного сервера.

Comment: Надеюсь, вы уже оценили [все трудности и проблемы этого занятия](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/why-you-may-not-want-to-run-your-own-mail-server) и твёрдо уверены, что вам действительно надо именно это.

Comment: Знаю только приблизительно. Если с этим не получится, буду спрашивать как использовать SMTP от Яндекс-почты для домена (Яндекс.ПДД), т.к. весь день потратил зря, занимаясь настройкой - выдает ошибку "send AUTH command first". Настраивал по нескольким англоязычным руководствам - эффект был один. Возможно, тут какая-то особенность Raspbian, о которой я не знаю?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> в данном случае это Raspbian на Raspberry Pi, но это не принципиально

это как раз принципиально. в том смысле, что в разных дистрибутивах пакеты устанавливаются по-разному.

в дистрибутиве *raspbian*, который основан на дистрибутиве *debian gnu/linux* пакеты из репозитория устанавливаются пакетным менеджером *apt**.

сначала надо обновить список пакетов:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

затем устанавливать пакеты:

```
$ sudo apt-get install имя-пакета ...
```

удалить пакеты:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove имя-пакета ...
```

---

если вы **действительно** хотите установить именно программу *sendmail*, то она находится в одноимённом пакете. но по личному опыту я бы предложил воздержаться от использования этой программы в пользу какой-нибудь более дружелюбной к <s>человеку</s> администратору реализации *smtp-сервера*. например, *exim4* или *postfix* (пакеты с этими программами так и называются).

Comment: Да, это понятно. По сути, с точки зрения установки программ это Debian. Поэтому и говорю, что не принципиально. Попробую тогда другие программы для отправки почты.

Comment: Ответ не совсем такой, какой я ожидал, но за наводку о exim4 большое спасибо, установил, настроил - то, что нужно.